# Использование кода из pull request в react native, npm

Tags: ios, npm, react-native, momentjs

Добрый день! Делаю первые шаги в react native.

Столкнулся с проблемой при подключении библиотеки

```
Gifted Chat:
require() must have a single string literal argument
```

На гитхабе нашел pull request для исправления ошибки, теперь осталось понять как подключить вместо автоматически подтягиваемой либы этот пулл реквест.

Просто удалить либу из node-modules и залить туда новые файлы не помогло

Comment: Если нужный вам pull request есть в отдельном бранче (*branch*), вы можете установить конкретный бранч. Посмотрите этот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732397/install-specific-branch-from-github-using-npm

Comment: Поскольку отдельного бранча нету, выход только один. Форкнуть проект и применить себе нужный пулл реквест.